# How can I efficiently support Entity Framework SQL logging in production?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, logging, trace

We're using Entity Framework 4.0. When we encounter a problem in production, we'd like to be able to temporarily enable logging of all SQL statements. We don't have enough permissions on the production SQL Server to run SQL Profiler.

Is there a good logging option that (a) can be turned on and off via a config file setting, and (b) doesn't add significant overhead when it's turned off?

I've read about the [Tracing and Caching Provider Wrappers for Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32). This sounds good... but it's sample code and isn't officially supported. So I'm not sure if it would be appropriate for production. I also don't know if the wrapper would add too much overhead even when logging is turned off. Has anyone had good experiences with these wrappers?

Thanks for your help,
Richard

Comment: "We don't have enough permissions on the production SQL Server to run SQL Profiler." - Have you asked for alter TRACE ? Its a long shot, most DBAs won't give it, but it's easy to turn it off agaian....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity framework and queries' SQL logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174261/entity-framework-and-queries-sql-logging)

Comment: Tracing provider wrapper is not officially supported but it is code like any other. If you want logging you will either use it or you will write same code by yourselves and it will still be "unsupported".

Comment: Thanks Mitch - I'll talk to our DBA about ALTER TRACE permission.

Comment: You're right Ladislav. I don't doubt the quality of the code... it's more a question of (a) is the performance overhead acceptable for production, or only for dev/testing, and (b) if we run into a problem with it, is there a way to get help? Writing our own isn't an option if it requires that much code. It's a choice between using the wrappers, or going through our DBA to set up a profiler trace each time we need to monitor.

Comment: We've decided not to use the provider wrapper, since there's not enough information about using it in production. We'll go through our DBA when necessary to set up SQL Profiler traces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code sample has been [released in a NuGet package](http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/). It's been slightly modified to tie into the built-in .NET tracing system (using a `TraceSource` instead of just file/console logging).

I've used it on a couple of different projects, and I've found it helpful. It can be enabled/disabled from app.config/web.config just like any other `TraceSource`.

I haven't had any performance issues, but I'm only using it in single-user scenarios.