# How to tweak SQL code generated by Linq and get the same object type in result of execution

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, debugging, expression-trees

I want to use `((ObjectQuery)IQueryable).ToTraceString()` to obtain and tweak SQL code that is going to be executed by LINQ, then run it using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`, then feed back to Linq to produce the same  resulting objects as if it was not altered.

I tweak it in such a way that it returns same structure (same columns), for example, I may just add comments to be able to easily filter queries in SQL Server Profiler.

It is easy to consume those results for things like Count or 1-4 columns without mapping to same resulting Linq type.

But when I have a query that returns complex type generated by Linq expression, I would like to feed  SqlDataReader results back to Entity Framework to get the same Linq result type that was used to generate that query ?

I am looking for any way of tweaking underlying Linq query, it does not have to be through SqlCommand.

Comment: What type of "tweak" do you want to do?  There are a lot of things you can do that would affect the underlying SQL, so it may be possible to implement the effect you want up front.

Comment: 1) To replace table name with another table or view name that is not part of edmx. 2) Insert comments to identify and filter queries in SQL Server Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SqlQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx) to write your own queries in [Entity SQL syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738573.aspx), but although it has a syntax for inserting comments in the query string, the comments don't show in the SQL profiler.

So if inserting comments is the only tweak you need, you'll have to find something else, for instance [custom logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863740/how-can-i-efficiently-support-entity-framework-sql-logging-in-production). For other "tweaks" SqlQuery might be appropriate.

Comment: Can I use SqlQuery<T> to replace one of table names with another table  or view name that does not have same Foreign Key relationships defined as original table and is not imported into edmx, but all data are such as that all query joins and fields are still valid after that replacement ?

Comment: Everything must be registered in the ObjectContext, but you should be able to join ([JOIN FROM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387167.aspx)) on fields that have no known relationship in the data context.